# How to import Matlab code to Latex?

Tags: matlab, latex

I have used `Matlab prettifier` package with `\lstinputlistings{file.m}` command but its not working. Is there another way to import your MATLAB Code to the LATEX?

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Do you get errors, or is the code not highlighted correctly?

Comment: Not working means these commands are not giving required results. I tried to import my matlab files into my LATEX document using commands mentioned in my question but LATEX is pointing out some error so I am not able to import my script files to the LATEX document and looking forward for some alternative way.